# Import into database from csv file, utf8 issues

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have an csv file that I have to download daily and update it into an sql databse. I first used phpmyadmin to get all the names of the table so I can create the query. Let's say the file has 170 rows and when imported using phpmyadmin, it imports all 170 rows. Using the sql query :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `import` (
  `AnnonceurCodeListe` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnnonceurSocieteNom` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnnonceurSocieteMarque` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnnonceurSocieteAdresse` varchar(37) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnnonceurSocieteAdresseSuite` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnnonceurSocieteCodePostal` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnnonceurSocieteVille` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnnonceurContactsNoms` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnnonceurContactsTelephones` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnnonceurContactsTelephones2` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnnonceurContactsEmails` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeIdentifiantVehicule` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeReferenceVehicule` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeNumeroPolice` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeStatutStock` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeAnnee` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeDate1Mec` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeGenreLibelle` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeMarque` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeFamille` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeVersion` varchar(51) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeModele` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeTypeMine` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeEnergieLibelle` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculePuissanceFiscale` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculePuissanceReelle` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeCylindree` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeNbPlaces` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeNbPortes` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeKilometrage` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeKmGaranti` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeCouleur` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeBoiteLibelle` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeNbRapports` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculePrixVenteTTC` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculePremiereMain` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeGarantieLibelle` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeDestinationLibelle` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeCategorieLibelle` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeEquipementsSerie` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeEquipementsOption` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeSiteLibelle` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculePhotos` varchar(189) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeCo2` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehiculeCommentairePublic` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/data.csv' 
INTO TABLE import 
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

It imports only 88 rows with 64 warnings saying `1262 Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns`, this column contains special characters like `é` and `à`, I tried augmenting the initial value of each varchar, tried changing the utf but then it gets imported with weird stuff inside of it. I even tried getting the length of the row affected and it was smaller than the varchar limit. I checked multiple topics about utf8 and the warning I'm getting and none of the solutions were able to help me. Thank you in advance!

```
"AnnonceurCodeListe";"AnnonceurSocieteNom";"AnnonceurSocieteMarque";"AnnonceurSocieteAdresse";"AnnonceurSocieteAdresseSuite";"AnnonceurSocieteCodePostal";"AnnonceurSocieteVille";"AnnonceurContactsNoms";"AnnonceurContactsTelephones";"AnnonceurContactsTelephones2";"AnnonceurContactsEmails";"VehiculeIdentifiantVehicule";"VehiculeReferenceVehicule";"VehiculeNumeroPolice";"VehiculeStatutStock";"VehiculeAnnee";"VehiculeDate1Mec";"VehiculeGenreLibelle";"VehiculeMarque";"VehiculeFamille";"VehiculeVersion";"VehiculeModele";"VehiculeTypeMine";"VehiculeEnergieLibelle";"VehiculePuissanceFiscale";"VehiculePuissanceReelle";"VehiculeCylindree";"VehiculeNbPlaces";"VehiculeNbPortes";"VehiculeKilometrage";"VehiculeKmGaranti";"VehiculeCouleur";"VehiculeBoiteLibelle";"VehiculeNbRapports";"VehiculePrixVenteTTC";"VehiculePremiereMain";"VehiculeGarantieLibelle";"VehiculeDestinationLibelle";"VehiculeCategorieLibelle";"VehiculeEquipementsSerie";"VehiculeEquipementsOption";"VehiculeSiteLibelle";"VehiculePhotos";"VehiculeCo2";"VehiculeCommentairePublic"
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28754592";"2875";"2723";"ST";"2011";"05-08-2011";"Utilitaires légers";"MERCEDES";"VITO FG";"110 CDI LONG 2T8 FRIGORIFIQUE";"VITO FG 110 CDI LONG 2T8 FRIGORIFIQUE";"";"Diesel";"7";"95";"2143";"3";"4";"135224";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"6";"18900";"VRAI";"";"";"FOURGON 4 PORTES";"";"";"VENTE";"28754592_01_hd.jpg|28754592_02_hd.jpg|28754592_03_hd.jpg|28754592_04_hd.jpg|28754592_05_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28724592";"2872";"2720";"ST";"2010";"04-03-2010";"Utilitaires légers";"VOLKSWAGEN";"CADDY VAN";"1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"CADDY VAN 1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"";"Diesel";"8";"105";"1896";"0";"4";"235730";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"5";"5400";"VRAI";"";"";"FOURGONNETTE 4 P.";"";"";"VENTE";"28724592_01_hd.jpg|28724592_02_hd.jpg|28724592_03_hd.jpg|28724592_04_hd.jpg|28724592_05_hd.jpg|28724592_06_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28894592";"2889";"2736";"ST";"2014";"16-12-2014";"Remorques";"DELCROIX";"TMC";"REMORQUE FRIGORIFIQUE BI-TEMP";"TMC REMORQUE FRIGORIFIQUE BI-TEMP";"";"";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"Non garanti";"BLANC";"";"0";"16680";"VRAI";"";"";"Coupé cabriolet";"";"";"VENTE";"28894592_01_hd.jpg|28894592_02_hd.jpg|28894592_03_hd.jpg|28894592_04_hd.jpg|28894592_05_hd.jpg|28894592_06_hd.jpg|28894592_07_hd.jpg|28894592_08_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28634592";"2863";"2711";"ST";"2007";"08-10-2007";"Utilitaires légers";"VOLKSWAGEN";"CADDY VAN";"1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"CADDY VAN 1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"";"Diesel";"8";"105";"1896";"0";"4";"158470";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"5";"4990";"VRAI";"3 MOIS OU 5000 KM";"";"FOURGONNETTE 4 P.";"";"";"VENTE";"28634592_01_hd.jpg|28634592_02_hd.jpg|28634592_03_hd.jpg|28634592_04_hd.jpg|28634592_05_hd.jpg|28634592_06_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28584592";"2858";"2706";"ST";"2009";"13-06-2009";"Utilitaires légers";"VOLKSWAGEN";"CADDY VAN";"1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"CADDY VAN 1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"";"Diesel";"8";"105";"1896";"0";"4";"168179";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"5";"5990";"VRAI";"";"";"FOURGONNETTE 4 P.";"";"";"VENTE";"28584592_01_hd.jpg|28584592_02_hd.jpg|28584592_03_hd.jpg|28584592_04_hd.jpg|28584592_05_hd.jpg|28584592_06_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28614592";"2861";"2709";"ST";"2008";"03-12-2008";"Utilitaires légers";"VOLKSWAGEN";"CADDY VAN";"1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"CADDY VAN 1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"";"Diesel";"8";"105";"1896";"0";"4";"138378";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"5";"5990";"VRAI";"";"";"FOURGONNETTE 4 P.";"";"";"VENTE";"";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28524592";"2852";"2700";"ST";"2009";"17-06-2009";"Utilitaires légers";"VOLKSWAGEN";"CADDY VAN";"1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"CADDY VAN 1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"";"Diesel";"8";"105";"1896";"0";"4";"164475";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"5";"5990";"VRAI";"";"";"FOURGONNETTE 4 P.";"";"";"VENTE";"28524592_01_hd.jpg|28524592_02_hd.jpg|28524592_03_hd.jpg|28524592_04_hd.jpg|28524592_05_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28444592";"2844";"2692";"ST";"2008";"03-12-2008";"Utilitaires légers";"VOLKSWAGEN";"CADDY VAN";"1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"CADDY VAN 1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"";"Diesel";"8";"105";"1896";"0";"4";"167226";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"5";"5490";"VRAI";"";"";"FOURGONNETTE 4 P.";"";"";"VENTE";"28444592_01_hd.jpg|28444592_02_hd.jpg|28444592_03_hd.jpg|28444592_04_hd.jpg|28444592_05_hd.jpg|28444592_06_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28174592";"2817";"2665";"ST";"2011";"05-08-2011";"Utilitaires légers";"MERCEDES";"VITO FG";"110 CDI LONG 2T7 FRIGORIFIQUE";"VITO FG 110 CDI LONG 2T7 FRIGORIFIQUE";"";"Diesel";"7";"0";"0";"0";"0";"102462";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"6";"19440";"VRAI";"";"";"Fourgon";"";"";"VENTE";"28174592_01_hd.jpg|28174592_02_hd.jpg|28174592_03_hd.jpg|28174592_04_hd.jpg|28174592_05_hd.jpg|28174592_06_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28144592";"2814";"2662";"ST";"2011";"21-01-2011";"Utilitaires légers";"MERCEDES";"VITO FG";"110CDI LONG 2T7 FRIGORIFIQUE";"VITO FG 110CDI LONG 2T7 FRIGORIFIQUE";"";"Diesel";"7";"0";"0";"0";"0";"108524";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"6";"16500";"FAUX";"";"";"Fourgon";"";"";"VENTE";"";"0";""

"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28764592";"2876";"2724";"ST";"2011";"05-08-2011";"Utilitaires légers";"MERCEDES";"SPRINTER FG";"210 32S FRIGORIFIQUE";"SPRINTER FG 210 32S FRIGORIFIQUE";"";"Diesel";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"168927";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"6";"15000";"VRAI";"";"";"Fourgon";"";"";"VENTE";"";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28744592";"2874";"2722";"ST";"2008";"03-12-2008";"Utilitaires légers";"VOLKSWAGEN";"CADDY VAN";"1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"CADDY VAN 1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"";"Diesel";"8";"105";"1896";"0";"4";"180570";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"5";"4490";"VRAI";"3 MOIS OU 5000 KM";"";"FOURGONNETTE 4 P.";"";"";"VENTE";"28744592_01_hd.jpg|28744592_02_hd.jpg|28744592_03_hd.jpg|28744592_04_hd.jpg|28744592_05_hd.jpg|28744592_06_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28884592";"2888";"2735";"ST";"2014";"16-12-2014";"Remorques";"DELCROIX";"TMC";"MONO TEMPERATURE";"TMC MONO TEMPERATURE";"";"";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"Non garanti";"BLANC";"";"0";"14400";"VRAI";"";"";"Coupé cabriolet";"";"";"VENTE";"28884592_01_hd.jpg|28884592_02_hd.jpg|28884592_03_hd.jpg|28884592_04_hd.jpg|28884592_05_hd.jpg|28884592_06_hd.jpg|28884592_07_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28694592";"2869";"2717";"ST";"2009";"20-06-2009";"Utilitaires légers";"VOLKSWAGEN";"CADDY VAN";"1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"CADDY VAN 1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"";"Diesel";"8";"105";"1896";"0";"4";"173785";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"5";"5990";"VRAI";"";"";"FOURGONNETTE 4 P.";"";"";"VENTE";"28694592_01_hd.jpg|28694592_02_hd.jpg|28694592_03_hd.jpg|28694592_04_hd.jpg|28694592_05_hd.jpg|28694592_06_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28644592";"2864";"2712";"ST";"2009";"17-06-2009";"Utilitaires légers";"VOLKSWAGEN";"CADDY VAN";"1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"CADDY VAN 1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"";"Diesel";"8";"105";"1896";"0";"4";"231449";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"5";"4990";"FAUX";"";"";"FOURGONNETTE 4 P.";"";"";"VENTE";"28644592_01_hd.jpg|28644592_02_hd.jpg|28644592_03_hd.jpg|28644592_04_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28604592";"2860";"2708";"ST";"2009";"17-06-2009";"Utilitaires légers";"VOLKSWAGEN";"CADDY VAN";"1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"CADDY VAN 1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"";"Diesel";"8";"105";"1896";"0";"4";"170838";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"5";"5990";"VRAI";"";"";"FOURGONNETTE 4 P.";"";"";"VENTE";"28604592_01_hd.jpg|28604592_02_hd.jpg|28604592_03_hd.jpg|28604592_04_hd.jpg|28604592_05_hd.jpg|28604592_06_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28554592";"2855";"2701";"ST";"2009";"20-06-2009";"Utilitaires légers";"VOLKSWAGEN";"CADDY VAN";"1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"CADDY VAN 1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"";"Diesel";"8";"105";"1896";"0";"4";"199905";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"5";"5490";"VRAI";"";"";"FOURGONNETTE 4 P.";"";"";"VENTE";"28554592_01_hd.jpg|28554592_02_hd.jpg|28554592_03_hd.jpg|28554592_04_hd.jpg|28554592_05_hd.jpg|28554592_06_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28484592";"2848";"2696";"ST";"2007";"08-10-2007";"Utilitaires légers";"VOLKSWAGEN";"CADDY VAN";"1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"CADDY VAN 1.9 TDI 105CH CONFORT CLIM";"";"Diesel";"8";"105";"1896";"0";"4";"183383";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"5";"4990";"VRAI";"3 MOIS OU 5000 KM";"";"FOURGONNETTE 4 P.";"";"";"VENTE";"28484592_01_hd.jpg|28484592_02_hd.jpg|28484592_03_hd.jpg|28484592_04_hd.jpg|28484592_05_hd.jpg|28484592_06_hd.jpg|28484592_07_hd.jpg";"0";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28344592";"2834";"2682";"ST";"2008";"26-08-2008";"Voitures";"BMW";"SERIE 3";"(E90) 318D 143CH CONFORT";"SERIE 3 (E90) 318D 143CH CONFORT";"";"Diesel";"7";"143";"1995";"5";"4";"176144";"Non garanti";"ANTHRACITE";"Manuelle";"6";"7590";"FAUX";"";"";"Berline";"";"";"VENTE";"28344592_01_hd.jpg|28344592_02_hd.jpg|28344592_03_hd.jpg|28344592_04_hd.jpg|28344592_05_hd.jpg|28344592_06_hd.jpg";"123";""
"ddda";"Name";"";"Addresse";"";"8888";"";"NAME";"Phone";"Phone2";"Mail";"28154592";"2815";"2663";"ST";"2011";"11-05-2011";"Utilitaires légers";"MERCEDES";"VITO FG";"110CDI LONG 2T7 FRIGORIFIQUE";"VITO FG 110CDI LONG 2T7 FRIGORIFIQUE";"";"Diesel";"7";"0";"0";"0";"0";"165278";"Garanti";"BLANC";"Manuelle";"6";"15000";"VRAI";"";"";"Fourgon";"";"";"VENTE";"";"0";""
```

The first 10 are not importing, the others under are.

Comment: Can you upload your data file somehow, to test it? Which version of MySQL you are using.

Comment: @Vivek updated the question at the end with 4 rows that fails to import. And using MySQL 5.7.14 from wamp.

Comment: It's loading for me, The "IGNORE 1 ROWS" actually ignoring your first records and looks like you are not getting all of 4 records imported. I just tried it's importing for me. Can you some data say 20-30 rows with that most of record getting failed.

Comment: The first row is for the names of the columns, I re edited the question with 10 imports that do not work and 10 that do work. @Vivek

Comment: In my case still it's working :), I am using 5.7.21 just upper minor version of Linux. But it should be a problem.  I think the problem with OS, as you are using Windows. In windows might be it should be handle in different way.

Comment: But it doesn't make any sense? Why would it work in phpmyadmin import and not by sql query? Then I'm doing something wrong no?@Vivek

Comment: Thank you @Vivek for pointing out the windows issue, I figured it out. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why I've got this error, it was in the `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` I had to add `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` for windows system, thanks for Vivek for pointing it out, and now everything works with no problem!